# A cone being intercepted by a slanted plane

Tags: plotting, code-request

I have the 3d cone:

```
Plot3D[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, Mesh -> None, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

I need a slanted plane intersecting it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Add a plane to your plot? e.g. `Plot3D[{-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -1 - x - y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Comment: I don't quite get what you're after.  You know the equation of a cone but not of a plane?  Any linear function of `x` and `y` yields a plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[
 {
  {Opacity[0.5], Cone[{{0,0,0}, {0,0,3}}, 1]},
  {Yellow, Opacity[0.5], Polygon[{{-1,-1,1}, {-1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,-1,2}, {-1,-1,1}}]}
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Or play around with this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   {LightBlue, Opacity[0.5], Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, rcone]},
   {Yellow, Opacity[0.5], 
    Polygon[{{-1,-1,1}, {-1,1,1}, {1,1,m}, {1,-1,m}, {-1,-1,1}}]}
   }
  ],
 {rcone, .5, 2}, {m, 1, 3}
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

let's say you have a plane:

```
myPlane=-8-x-2y
```

you can use Plot3D like so;

```
Plot3D[{-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], myPlane}, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

you can pimp your plot with [RegionFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html):

```
Plot3D[{-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], myPlane}, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, -10 < z < 10], BoxRatios -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

and or and specify [ViewPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewPoint.html) for visualization:

[image]