# how can I bold the outline of conic section as the plane intercepts the cone?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

```
Plot3D[{-5 - x - y, -Sqrt[8 x^2 + 8 y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: a plane intercepting a cone]

Comment: You could use Solve to find the equation of the intersection and then use ParametricPlot3D to plot it. Combine it with the other plot using Show.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use RegionIntersection with Cone and InfinitePlane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [About Slicing through Graphics3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60888/about-slicing-through-graphics3d)

Comment: @jens It is my impression (but I may be wrong here) that the OP wants to see the plane and cone and their intersection (accentuated). The post you referred to has the plane slice off a piece of the cone, which is not the same.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'd suggest the OP clarify the question so as to not waste time with misinterpretations...

Comment: @jens That would indeed be better. I just noted that the question is a follow-up of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75917/a-cone-being-intercepted-by-a-slanted-plane). It suggests that what is needed is the outline of the intersection, but who knows?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75917/a-cone-being-intercepted-by-a-slanted-plane

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Did you read the comments above (and the question)?

Comment: To the closers: The OP has update the question to indicate that she wants the outline of the intersection be marked. This is not the case in the question linked as duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using `BoundaryStyle`**

Use the option `BoundaryStyle` and set the option value to `{{1, 2} -> Directive[Thick, Red]}`:

```
Plot3D[{-5 - x - y, -Sqrt[8 x^2 + 8 y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 BoundaryStyle -> {{1, 2} -> Directive[Thick, Red]} ]
```

[image]

Note: This particular usage for `BoundaryStyle` in not documented. The earliest reference on this site is [this answer by Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972/125)

**Using `MeshFunctions`**

Use the difference between the two functions as the setting for option `MeshFunctions`:

```
Plot3D[{-5 - x - y, -Sqrt[8 x^2 + 8 y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {-5 - # - #2 - (-Sqrt[8 #^2 + 8 #2^2]) &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Red, Thick]}}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Of course. Interestingly, your specific application of BoundaryStyle does not seem to be documented on its documentation page. Where did you learn about this?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, thanks for the vote. It is not in documentation.  I have a faint memory of having seen something like this on this site; but i could not find it with the usual key words. Btw, it does not work in some cases where one would wish it would, e.g. i could not find a way to make it work in [this q/a[(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58045/125)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, found the reference: [Daniel's answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972/125)

Comment: Ah, that's  great! I see that I voted for it, so I should  have known.

Answer (score 6):

Find equations for intersection:

```
Solve[-5 - x - y == -Sqrt[8 x^2 + 8 y^2], x]
```

> {{x -> 1/7 (5 + y - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[25 + 10 y - 6 y^2])}, {x ->
>       1/7 (5 + y + 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[25 + 10 y - 6 y^2])}}

Range of y:

```
Solve[25 + 10 y - 6 y^2 == 0, y]
```

> {{y -> 5/6 (1 - Sqrt[7])}, {y -> 5/6 (1 + Sqrt[7])}}

Draw intersection:

```
inter =
 With[
   {
     x1 = 1/7 (5 + y - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[25 + 10 y - 6 y^2]), 
     x2 = 1/7 (5 + y + 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[25 + 10 y - 6 y^2])
   },
  ParametricPlot3D[{{x1, y, -5 - x1 - y}, {x2, y, -5 - x2 - y}}, 
    {y, 5/6 (1 - Sqrt[7]), 5/6 (1 + Sqrt[7])}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Add other objects:

```
cone = Cone[{{0, 0, -Sqrt[200]}, {0, 0, 0}}, 5];
plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, -5}, {-5, 0, 0}, {0, -5, 0}}];

Show[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], cone, plane}],
 inter
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]